# Is there a way to read from a smart contract If client has not metamask (or sth else) installed?

Tags: ethereum, smartcontracts, web3js

We're trying to build a dapp to share and display classifieds. Classifieds are being in the smart contract. People who connected their Metamask accounts can display adds. But we want to show them to everyone. Is there any way to do it?

Thanks for your responses.

Comment: A solution could be to create a server side application that will connect to the smart contract with its own key and the expose data to all users.